# Excel formula to find similar values in a column and return value based on output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which lists all the products that I have for sale. These products are grouped into separate categories. If any one product in a category is out of inventory, I want to classify all products in that category as out of inventory.

Can I do this in an if statement? I need to add multiple other if conditions to this formula. If I can't do it in an if statement, how can I do this?

I've tried googling it but i'm sure i'm not searching for the right thing as i'm not getting any solution.

As a simplified example, I've listed the categories and the inventory of products in them. If the inventory of any product in a category is 0, the output should be "No Inventory" else the output should be "Inventory". You can see that the inventory of item 4 which belongs to category A is zero, therefore the output for all items in category A should be "No Inventory"

```
Categories  Inventory   Output
A           2324      No Inventory
A           66        No Inventory
A           9129      No Inventory
A           0         No Inventory
B           1453         Inventory
B           967          Inventory
B           5109         Inventory
B           75           Inventory
B           1069         Inventory
```

I'd appreciate your help in making this work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*the inventory of item 4 which belongs to category A is zero, therefore the output for all items in category A should be "No Inventory"*

So if the stock of any item in a category is 0, then **all items** from that category should be marked as *No Inventory*?

In that case, you can use the formula COUNTIFS combined with an IF. With COUNTIFS you can count how many rows of a specific category and inventory 0 you got. If that count is 1 or more, then with an IF return *No Inventory*. If not, return *Inventory*.

I copied your dataset:

[image]

The formula I've used in column C is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;A2;$B$2:$B$10;0)>0;"No inventory";"Inventory")
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE 2:** OP wants *to classify all items in category A which are not zero as "Pause this"*

Not sure if I understand this properly, but I guess that you want to check if the item inventory is 0. If true, then that specific item should return *Pause this*. If not, then return *No Inventory*. And of course, if none of the items of a specific category got stock 0, then it should return *Inventory*.

That's what I have understood of your comment. You can adapt the previous formula like this, using a second IF.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;A2;$B$2:$B$10;0)>0;IF(B2=0;"Pause this";"No inventory");"Inventory")
```

I get this using this formula:

[image]

Hope you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I asked for - thank you! As a follow-up question, if I want to classify all items in category A which are not zero as "Pause this"  - how would I do that?

Comment: Upvote for the use of Countifs to solve the problem. I got as far as `=IF(OR(B2=0,IFNA(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(0,B:B,0))=A2,FALSE())),"No Inventory","Inventory")` which only works for one instance of no inventory and gave up.

Comment: @Abhay what is your expected output for this follow up question? You could add this formula in another column: `=IF(AND(B2=0,C2="No inventory),"Pause this","")` which will put "pause this" against every line that isn't zero but the category is out of stock. If you want to change the actual numbers to "Pause this" this can be done but I advise against it as it might break @Foxfire's formula.

Comment: If you need it in a different column, then @Plutian answer should work for you :)

Comment: Wow you are amazing. Thank you for your help!